# Can't launch activity

Tags: android

I am trying to launch an App on Android eumulator, but it doesn't start:

```
niko@desk :~/android-sdk$ ./platform-tools/adb shell cmd activity start-activity org.afterether.wallet
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] pkg=org.afterether.wallet }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=org.afterether.wallet }
niko@desk :~/android-sdk$ platform-tools/adb shell 'pm list packages -f'|grep -i after
package:/data/app/org.afterether.wallet-2gvsNvL7K3-pb1CdEr0SHQ==/base.apk=org.afterether.wallet
niko@desk :~/android-sdk$
```

On the logcat I can only see 1 line:

```
04-30 19:14:06.163 12578 13821 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=org.afterether.wallet} from uid 2000
```

This only happens with Android API 28, on 26 can I launch the app perfectly. I am using x86 32 bit emulator to do these tests. Clicking on the icon App **DOES** work, it only fails when launching from the `adb`

My main question is: **how should I debug to find out why it is failing to start my App?**

My manifest begins like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest package="org.afterether.wallet" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="auto">
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:label="-- %%INSERT_APP_NAME%% --" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
                <activity android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation" android:name="org.afterether.wallet.QShareActivity" android:label="-- %%INSERT_APP_NAME%% --" android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:taskAffinity="">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Hi Nulik, I have tried your code on a real device (xiaomi API 28) and it works fine. 
can you show more of lofcat output?

Comment: @MohamedFotouhShalan I solved it. The problem was that I don't have `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` in application intent filter, so  the launch has to be done like this: `./platform-tools/adb  shell monkey -p org.afterether.wallet -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
`

Comment: okay, I see this doesn't happen to me because I used to run from android studio not from the command line